# Fullscreen background photo with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Lots of websites now have a fullscreen background photo (or even video, such as http://www.paypal.fr).

**How to add a fullscreen background photo to a Bootstrap page like this demo:**

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/

I tried

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <img src="photo.jpg">
```

but the photo was bad positioned.

Comment: Have you tried asking the same question in Google? You don't need to include Bootstrap in your question. It can be done with css or jQuery. I recommend you install Firebug extension from Firefox, to inspect how other websites are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. You could do it via css:

```
body {
    background: url('photo.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: If I resize the broswer window, then the image is strechted and does not keep aspect ratio. You know how solve that?

Comment: If you want the image to fit within the background, set background-size to contain. This will put borders around the image you can style using other css background properties. If you want the image to fill the background, set this to cover. This will cut off some of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can add a css rule to `body` in order to display a picture as a background.

```
body
{
    background-image: url('photo.jpg');
}
```

In addition to this, if you want background image to cover whole screen, you may add `background-size` property.

```
body
{
    background-image: url('photo.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If you do not want to resize image on narrower screens to keep aspect ratio, you may write conditional rule like the following. Remember to prepare photos differently resized for some screen sizes.

```
/*for screens larger than 959px */
@media (min-width: 960px) {
    body {
        background-image: url('photo-xl.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
    }
} 

/*for screens larger than 767px */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-image: url('photo-lg.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
    }
} 
/*for screens larger than 479px */
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-image: url('photo-xs.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. But if I resize the broswer window, then the image is strechted and does not keep aspect ratio. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size: cover;` This will give you the aspect ratio you are looking for

Se [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxByeg)

```
body{
     background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b2/Brad_Pitt_boxing.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;  
     background-size:cover;
}
```